# Terminal emulator for GNOME with display features like Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, terminal, gnome

Is there a terminal emulator which works well in an Ubuntu desktop and provides the following features which Mac OS X's Terminal application has?

- Rewrapping text when the window is resized.
- A “Clear” command which clears scrollback (as the shell `clear` does not) and does not clear the cursor's line (typically containing a prompt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/)? It's cross-platform  I used it under OS X for a good while before switching to iTerm and remember reflowing.

The standard answer to 'what is a better terminal' under X11 is `rxvt-unicode` (available via `sudo aptitude install rxvt-unicode`) aka `urxvt`. However, rxvt-unicode doesn't have a GUI for configuration or anything –– it's definitely slanted to the power user.

Another solution might be to run `screen` inside your current terminal.

Comment: “Sadly, we don't have the resources to support two implementations, so reflowing is no longer an option; it's gone from the code.” — Terminator's site. rxvt-unicode seems to be destructive on resize — do you know an option? I find that screen does rewrap, surprisingly. I will look into whether I can tweak it into doing what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making great progress in implementing rewrapping in VTE (gnome-terminal etc.). Please see the upstream bug at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=336238 , feel free to try my patch if you're a hacker kind. In case of any technical feedback, please comment in that upstream bug, thanks! Hopefully my work will soon end up in mainstream VTE.